# KDB replace null integer in all columns with int or float

Tags: kdb

Expanding this question,

[kdb+: replace null integer with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016789/kdb-replace-null-integer-with-0)

Ff I have a large table that contains different data types like float, int, timestamps, how can I expand this

```
0^tbl
```

to only get applied to columsn of a certain type. Currently, if I apply it to the full table, I get a type error and there must eb a smarter way than doing it column by column manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a functional apply based on the type of each column, something like the following:

```
q)t:([] a:9?`3;b:9#0N;c:9#0Nf;d:9#0Ni)
q)@[t;where (type each flip t) within 5 9h;0^]
a   b c d
---------
kdj 0 0 0
eeg 0 0 0
nce 0 0 0
jog 0 0 0
..
```

This works by applying 0^ to only the columns with types between 5 and 9 (i.e. short, int, long, real and float)

Hope this helps

Jonathon